# Adding ASP.NET page to running application ( IIS + SQL )

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

There is a running ASP.NET application (built and compiled) running on IIS + SQL server.
I have a requirement to add an ASPX page to provide some additional functionnality (without access to original VS project).

I built a simple ASPX page, and it is working fine (displaying Application Pool ID and SQL connection string, both directly or through myGetConnectionString()

```
<HTML>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ibody1" Runat="Server">
    Body1
<%=System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APP_POOL_ID", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process) %>
<%=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycon"].ConnectionString %>
<%=myGetConnectionString() %>
</asp:Content>
</HTML>
```

However as soon as i try to initiate a SQL connection

```
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(myGetConnectionString());
```

An error is generated, and is caught by the main application (can't seem to find log details).

Any help appreciated.
Please keep in mind that i don't have access to a developpement environnement, or the source of the application that is running (although i have admin access to IIS)

Comment: I removed the <sql> tag since this isn't related to the ANSI/ISO SQL _language_. Instead add a tag for the dbms used. Probably <sql-server>.

Comment: Perhaps add a break point to that line or wrap it in a catch block to see what exception your getting? Hard to help you fix an error/exception if you don't know what the exception is.

Comment: ASP.NET has moved away from live editing for a while now. You do need to work with the source code and republish.

Comment: Unless the site was published as a "web site" and includes the asps.cs (or aspx.vb) source code files, then IIS will not re-compile the .aspx page into a working .dll for the code in question.  So, the first question does the current site include the source code files (such as aspx.cs or aspx.vb). If it does not, then you don't have the required source code files to re-build that project. So the type of project will determine if you can simply copy a web page to the site with code that you desire to be compiled when the page is loaded - without source code files then this will not work.

Comment: However, if the current site has those aspx.cs (or aspx.vb) files, then you can create or add a new web page - you should still do this from Visual Studio, and if you have those source files, then you can (should) be able to copy the files to your dev computer, and use Visual Studio to add a new page with code behind.

Comment: If you can't provide error information, it's impossible to analyze the problem by just guessing. Please provide more details as mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: Thanks all for your feedback, i'll try try/catch logic, no aspx.cs available, only .dll, .js (jquery) and .css. However i do not want to include my page into the current web/application, just as a side page with SQL access to use data from application.

Comment: If you want to create a standalone ASPX page that can access the SQL Server data without integrating it directly into the existing ASP.NET application, you can create a separate ASP.NET web application project. This new project will contain your ASPX page along with any necessary code-behind files (if required) to handle SQL Server connections and data retrieval.